# Removing sensitive information from question edit history

Tags: support

A question was asked recently where the asker unknowingly included some personal account information that could be exploited by users with malicious intent. I edited the question to remove the sensitive information, but the information still remains in the question's edit history. Is there any way to permanently remove part of the edit history, or change it somehow such that the original edit with the personal information is no longer accessible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove the edit history from a question, you should flag the question for moderator attention so they can redact the edit history.